# In GitHub Actions, how to get the type of a trigger event as a variable?

Tags: github, github-actions

I’m trying to set up a GitHub action for when pull requests are opened or closed and I’d like to get the type of the trigger to add it to the message. The YAML is as follows:

```yaml
on:
    pull_request:
        types: [opened, closed, reopened] #I’d like to get which one has been triggered
```

For instance:

> User X has *opened* a pull request

Someone suggested `${{env.GITHUB_EVENT_NAME}}` but it’s empty. `${{github.event}}` seems to be a good place but it returns an object with the webhook payload and I don’t know if "types" is in it or how to get it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`${{github.event.action}}` should give you the action for the pull request.

Example:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, closed, reopened]
        
jobs:
  prJob:    
    name: Print info
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print GitHub event action
        run: |
          echo "${{ github.event.action }}"
```

The `github` context is documented at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context.
And the complete documentation for the event can be found here: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#pull_request

Comment: For others that end up in this thread looking to detect the event trigger name ("push", "pull_request", etc), use github.event_name